# MobileService Offline Sync PullAsync does not return

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am currently trying to update my Windows Phone App to use Mobile Services with Offline Sync.

I used the msdn getting started, but it wont work for me.

Everytime I call

```
await table.PullAsync("table", table.getQuery());
```

it never finishes (program doesnt continue).

Using fiddler I can see, that the client gets the correct response from the server.

What might be the problem?

Thanks!

Edit: When I do .GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(...) the callback gets called.. Why does await hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason is that somewhere in the call stack you do exactly that `GetAwaiter()` with a `GetResult()`, or something similar - this usually "hangs" the program on the second call because it is still awaiting a thread that never exited.

Always use `await` through out your app.

Also add the the [`ConfigureAwait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx)(false) to the `await`ed methods as far as possible, i.e:

```
await table.PullAsync("table", table.getQuery()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

More info on this matter on [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: You should also run in the debugger to see if any threads are blocked. If it's a deadlock, then ConfigureAwait could solve the problem.